# Question in conditional probability

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables of discrete type with the p.m.f.  $f_1(x)=\,_{n_1}\!C_x\,p^x(1-p)^{n_1-x}$, $x=0,1,...,n_1$ and $f_2(x)=\,_{n_2}\!C_y\,p^y(1-p)^{n_2-y}$, $y=0,1,...,n_2$ respectively, where $n_1,\:n_2$ are positive integers.

(a) Find the distribution of Z =X+Y      <- i got this.

(b) For $z\leq \min \{n_1,n_2\}$, find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Z=z$. <- i'm stuck with this!

I have difficulty finding the probability of $Z=z$ since $z$ is not a specific value but a minimum of two numbers. I also have no idea how to find the probability of $X\cap Z$ needed to find the conditional probability for the same reason above...

[Note: $_n \!C_r\equiv {{n} \choose {r}}$]

Comment: Does this help ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575459/conditional-distribution-of-binomial-random-variables-is-hypergeometric